# Cant replace li append with li appendTo

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this and it works fine.

```
$('#discussion').append('<li>' + myname + mymessage + '</li>');
```

but when i replace that with this, it's not working, why?

```
$('<li>' + myname + mymessage + '</li>').html().appendTo("#discussion");
```

I can paste the full code if it's necessary.

Comment: Why are you creating new elements and passing values to them just to get the HTML back, it seems like you're missing something, and if you explain why, and what you're trying to do, maybe we can help you, as that looks horrible.

Comment: Remove call to .html()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your call to `.html()` returns the **innerHTML** property of the dynamic `<li>` as a string, not the item itself.

Try this:

```
$('<li>' + myname + mymessage + '</li>').appendTo("#discussion");
```

Answer (score 3):

html() returns a string, and you can't append a string as jQuery methods only accept actual elements wrapped in $() as context :

```
$('<li />', {html :myname + mymessage}).appendTo("#discussion");
```

Comment: +1 thanks mr burns... a little complicated syntax but working as well